# ElementNotVisibleException | Testing AngularJs Apps with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am trying to the test an angularJs Frontend by using Selenium Webdriver with Java.

I would likte to send some keys to an email inputbox.
The problem I am facing is, that the inputbox seems to be invisivile for selenium. I guess this has something to do with the ng-hide directive from angular. To be clear, I can defenitly see the inputbox when the testautomation starts, so for me as a person the inputbox seems to be visible.

**Frontend Image:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input id="changedbyEmailInput" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="article.author.email" placeholder="Your Email" ng-hide="article.isTemp === false" style="">
```

**Javacode to get the textbox:**

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id("changedbyEmailInput"));
element.sendKeys(keys);
```

**Javacode with Timeout**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("changedbyEmailInput")));
```

I also tried to use an timout but it just timeouts, so I guess it just never changes it's state.

PS: If someone knows if this issue is easy to solve by using protractor please let me know. I am open to switch to protractor if it will solve my problem.

Thank you!

**Edit:**
The problem is solved. It has nothing to do with ng-hide. The id just wasn't uniqe. Therefore there was always one disabled inputbox.

Comment: Have you checked that the id is unique and not in a frame? Do you get a result by executing `document.querySelectorAll("[id='changedbyEmailInput']")` in the browser's console?

Comment: I found the issue. You were right, this id is not unique... So there is always one enabled inputbox and one disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `JavascriptExecutor` to set value as follows :-

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('changedbyEmailInput').value = arguments[0]", "value to set");
```

Hope it will help you...:)